# how to push data in inside array mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

i am trying to push array in document array my collection is

```
{
"_id": "58eed81af6f8e3788de703f9",
"first_name": "abc",
"vehicles": {
    "exhibit": "18",
    "title": "Motor Velicle Information for Donald French",
    "details": [
        {
            "year": "",
            "make_model": "",
            "registered_owner": "",
            "license_number": "",
            "date_of_purchase": "",
            "purchase_price": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

so what i want is to push data in `details` for that i had try like this

```
 Licensee.update({"_id":"58eed81af6f8e3788de703f9"},{
        $push:{
            "vehicles.details":data
        }
    },function(err,data){
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log('data',data);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('err',err);
        }
    });
```

and for this i create one schema i don't know is right or not

```
var licSchema = new SimpleSchema({
"_id":{
    type:String,
    label:"_id",
    optional: false,
},
"vehicles.details.year": {
    type: String,
    label: "year",
    optional: true,
},
"vehicles.details.make_model": {
    type: String,
    label: "make_model",
    optional: true,
}
```

});

where is my fault please give me solution .
Error `Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty`

Comment: Whats the error message here

Comment: `Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. AddToSet should be the right way.

```
const schema = new SimpleSchema({
    "vehicles.details.$.year": {
        type: String,
        label: "year",
        optional: true,
     },
    "vehicles.details.$.make_model": {
        type: String,
        label: "make_model",
        optional: true,
     }
 });

Licensee.update({"_id":"58eed81af6f8e3788de703f9"},{
    $addToSet:{
        "vehicles.details": data
    }
});
```

Comment: same Error i thing i fault is  in Schema.

Comment: can you check my schema

Comment: @kumbhaniBhavesh ya you're right. Check the updated answer.